# What is the package manager for the mysql docker image/container?

Tags: mysql, docker, package-management

I have a mysql image running and I want to install vim or nano text editors along with pip and other tools. I cant figure out the package manager for the mysql image.

I have tried yum, apk, apt, apt-get...

Comment: Why?  If you were running a standalone non-container MySQL server, why would you need a text editor inside the database server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be microdnf [from yansifw](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/960)

Comment: Hey I posted this a while ago and forgot about it but thanks you were correct it is microdnf!